# What's the type of primary key for the this table?

Tags: sql, primary-key

I'm not sure how to specify the types of the primary keys. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: table definition]

Comment: What do you mean under `type of the primary key`?

Answer (score 2):

It's a composite primary key, because key consists of mutiple columns.